# TFS Build Notification Tray Application stopped working

Tags: visual-studio-2010, build, tfs, monitoring

I've been using the Team Foundation Build Notification tray application to monitor builds in TFS for about 1.5 years continuously. As of today, the tray application no longer seems to be able to connect to the TFS server. The task bar application appears to be working but does not show any build definitions. I have stopped / re-started the tray application, VS 2010, Windows 7 etc, and nothing allows it to reconnect.

I am still able to connect to, and view, the build definitions through Team Explorer in Visual Studio 2010 so I know the server is up and running. As I understand it, the tray application should connect using the Visual Studio settings! All other developers on our team can still use the tray application without any problems, so that rules out some sort of security patch or modification.

Any suggestions other than unistalling / re-installing Studio? Is there a way to just un-install and re-install the Team Foundation Server Tools Build Notification monitoring application?

Comment: I recommend that you stop Build Notifications and VS, clean your Windows Temp and your User Temp directories and restart Build Notifications and VS.